# Conditonally bind images to RDLC pages

Tags: .net, report, rdlc

Considering the scenario where I print a number of invoices coming from different stores to a PDF document.

I initialize an image wrapper object with say 8 images (these are store logos) and dynamically it gets assigned to the report RDLC. But the issue is I get same image in every invoice page.

I get the storeId in the dataset, is it possible to assign store images to these pages depending on the storeid of the invoice, in order to distinguish invoices according to stores?

I tried with the following code (RDLC Code behind, by attaching the assembly)

```
Public Function StoreImage(Storeid as Integer) as Byte()
Try
    Return eCom.Handlers.LogoWrapper.GetImage(StoreId);
Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex.Message
End Try
End Function
```

Kindly guide me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: Vb.net or C# if its vb.net pls remove your  C#  tag and add Vb.net tag...

Comment: sry for that! I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass all images in using the Data-set and use and use a switch statement in the expression field of the image control to apply the correct field from the Data-Set.